# Reflection is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm studying linear transformations and i've just read the formal proof of the fact that reflection is a linear transformation.

If I had **not** read the proof, how **intuitively** is it possible to convince me (i knows the basics of linear algebra) that reflection is indeed a linear function?

Comment: A reflection of a parallelogram is a parallelogram?

Comment: I think the mirror line has to pass through the origin for it to be a linear transformation as it needs to map origin to itself.  That said linear transforms preserve straight lines.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown why is this sufficient ?

Comment: @Qwerto Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

More precisecly it is an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) and in particular [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) is an isometry.